# Django attribute error. 'module' object has no attribute 'rindex'

Tags: python, django

I've just started using django, only on chapter 3 of the online book.

I keep on getting this weird error when I try and access the site.

AttributeError at /test/
'module' object has no attribute 'rindex'

my urls.py is just

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite import hello
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
      ('^test/$',hello),
)
```

and my hello function is in mysite.
Python path is

```
['/home/james/django/mysite', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/home/james/django']
```

I don't really understand whats going on here. I'm assuming I'm overlooking something stupid, because it seems so straightforward. When I do from mysite import hello in the python interpreter, it doesn't raise any errors.

any help would  be great

edit:
traceback

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/
Django Version: 1.2.3
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.co
 ntrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages']
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  91.                         request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  217.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  123.             return self.callback, args, kwargs
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  134.             mod_name, func_name = get_mod_func(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_mod_func
  78.         dot = callback.rindex('.')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /test/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'rindex'
```

hello function is

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

Comment: Any traceback and code would be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably need to change

```
from mysite import hello
```

to something like

```
from mysite.hello_file import hello_view
```

And then use:

```
('^test/$',hello_view)
```

Because you need to pass a (view) function, not a file or module. As I think mgalgs was trying to explain, but I think a bit unclear for beginners.

Comment: Thanks. It helps me to run Hello world Django example.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when adding a Class Based View the following way:

```
url(r'^tv/$', views.MyTemplateView(), name='my_tv'),
```

of course `.as_view()` should be added to fix error `object has no attribute 'rindex'`:

```
url(r'^tv/$', views.MyTemplateView.as_view(), name='my_tv'),
```

Answer (score 4):

The url pattern should be tuples of strings, not a module. Something like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
      ('^test/$','hello.views.hello'), 
)
```

EDIT: You can also pass a callable to patterns. I simply had never seen it done that way before (the docs always pass a string). However, you're actually passing a module, not a string or a callable (so django gets confused and first treats it like it must be a callable since it's not a string but then goes back to [trying to treat it like a string](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L89), hence the call to `rindex`). Maybe you meant to pass `hello.views.hello` like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
      ('^test/$',hello.views.hello), 
)
```

Alternatively, you could change your import line to `from mysite.hello.views import hello`, or just use the string syntax (I believe `'hello.views.hello'` would do it as initially suggested).

Comment: Simply untrue. You *cannot* pass a module. You can, however, pass a callable. I've edited my answer to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',      
    ('r^test/$','hello.views.hello'),  )
```