# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rindex'

Tags: python, django

I'm giving up. I can't manage to fix this error, no matter how hard I try. (I checked the old question here: [Django attribute error. 'module' object has no attribute 'rindex'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052578/django-attribute-error-module-object-has-no-attribute-rindex) but with no better result).

I'm using Django 1.6.1 and Python 2.7.3.

My app is named 'pret', everything worked fine until I installed a new package (qrcode2.0) and had to re configure the Python interpreter in Eclipse. The interpreter works fine for Django, I can create new projects.

The traceback is:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pret/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'pret')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/arthur/workspace/PretD/pret/templates/pret/index.html, error at line 12
   'module' object has no attribute 'rindex'

12 :        <p>Vers la page de <a href=" {% url 'login' %} ">login</a>.<br/>
```

My urls.py from the project is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^pret/', include('pret.urls')),
)
```

My urls.py from the app is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from pret import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^menu/$', views.menu, name='menu'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.loginn, name='login'),
    #Others url follow, with the same pattern
)
```

And finally my views.py is:

```
from decimal import Decimal, InvalidOperation
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from itertools import chain


def loginn(request):
template = loader.get_template('pret/login.html')
#Blablabla, some code here
context = RequestContext(request, {
                                   'msg_log' : msg_log,
                                   'msg_redirect' : msg_redirect})

return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

#Others views follow
```

The whole index.html, if it is in any way interesting (French words, yay!):

```
{% load url from future %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mines Pret - Accueil</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{test}}</h1>

        <p>Vous vous trouvez sur la page d'accueil du site.</p>
        <p>Vers la page de <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>.<br/>
        Vers la page <a href="{% url 'inscription' %}">d'inscription</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried

```
{% url 'pret:login' %}
```

and others variants according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Keep in mind that I renamed my view "login" in "loginn" to avoid conflits with the built-in "login" method in Django. However, the name="login" attribute in urls.py seemed to do the job. The AttributeError is raised with all the others views ("inscription", for instance)

Thanks a lot for your help, the Stackoverflow community has helped many many times.

Comment: What happens if you use the string syntax instead of passing callables to the urls, so `url(r'^login/$', 'pret.views.loginn', name='login'),`

Comment: I have the weirdest feeling right now. It is fixed, but I don't know how and why. I can't answer my own question with such low reputation so I'll do it here.

For testing purposes I had changed my urls.py by importing each view with "from pret.views import menu", but it didn't work.

However, in order to show you the initial state where the bug appeared, I've rewritten urls.py as it is in my above question, and that somehow fixed the bug.

Comment: I've just tested the `url(r'^login/$', 'pret.views.loginn', name='login'),` variant and it works fine too. Anyway I'm sorry to provide such a weird answer to my question for fellow programmers who could be stuck with the same problem, but I'm as confused as you are...

Comment: You had an error in your urls.py file basically. when you were trying to pass in a view function (loginn, index, menu) you were accidently passing in a module, possibly the view module, hence the error message. "`module has no attribute 'rindex'`"